# How to clear/reset a select box option when i select the first option of another selectbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to reset the value of a select box every time I select the first option of another select box. As you can see in my code below I am using 2 select boxes. The first one contains some dates and the second select box contain some hours. I need to reset the value of the second select box when I select the first option of the dates select box. I can't figure out where I went wrong.

```js
$( document ).on( "change", ".date_list", function() {
if ( $('select[name=d_date]')[0].selectedIndex === 0 )
{
$("#d_time").val();
alert('HOLLA');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="date_list" name="d_date" id="d_date">
<option value="2020-02-19">Wednesday 19 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-20">Thursday 20 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-21">Friday 21 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-24">Monday 24 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-25">Tuesday 25 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-26">Wednesday 26 February</option>
</select>

<select class="time_list" name="d_time" id="d_time"><option value="9:56:00">09:56</option><option value="10:56:00">10:56</option><option value="11:56:00">11:56</option><option value="12:56:00">12:56</option><option value="13:56:00">13:56</option><option value="14:56:00">14:56</option><option value="15:56:00">15:56</option><option value="16:56:00">16:56</option><option value="17:56:00">17:56</option><option value="18:56:00">18:56</option><option value="19:56:00">19:56</option><option value="20:56:00">20:56</option><option value="21:56:00">21:56</option></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just setting an empty string `$("#d_time").val("");`
Adding an empty option in the select box is highly recommended.

```js
$( document ).on( "change", ".date_list", function() {
if ( $('select[name=d_date]')[0].selectedIndex === 0 )
{
$("#d_time").val("");

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="date_list" name="d_date" id="d_date">
<option value="2020-02-19">Wednesday 19 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-20">Thursday 20 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-21">Friday 21 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-24">Monday 24 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-25">Tuesday 25 February</option>
<option value="2020-02-26">Wednesday 26 February</option>
</select>

<select class="time_list" name="d_time" id="d_time"><option value="9:56:00">09:56</option><option value="10:56:00">10:56</option><option value="11:56:00">11:56</option><option value="12:56:00">12:56</option><option value="13:56:00">13:56</option><option value="14:56:00">14:56</option><option value="15:56:00">15:56</option><option value="16:56:00">16:56</option><option value="17:56:00">17:56</option><option value="18:56:00">18:56</option><option value="19:56:00">19:56</option><option value="20:56:00">20:56</option><option value="21:56:00">21:56</option></select>
```

Comment: Really now ? LOL. OK what i was thinking ??

Comment: @Designer Sorry I didn't get? Am I post the wrong solution?

Comment: Oh no your answer was absolutely correct. I just was blaming my self ;) I will pick your answer as the right ;)